# Create a Query to check if any Column in a table is Null

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have zero experience with SQL but am trying to learn how to validate tables. I am trying to see within a table if any of the columns are null.

Currently I have been going with a script that is just counting the number of nulls. I am doing this for each column. Is there a better script that I can use to check all the columns in a table?

```
select count(id) from schema.table where id is not null
```

If there are 100 records I would expect all columns to come back with 100 but if one column is null it will show a 0.

Comment: What does “if one column is null” mean? Do you want to know if there are any nulls stored in any column? Or do you want to know if any column contains only nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count each column in a single query by using `sum` and `case`:

```
select
  sum(case when Column1 is null then 1 else 0 end) Column1NullCount
  , sum(case when Column2 is null then 1 else 0 end) Column2NullCount
  -- ...
  , sum(case when ColumnN is null then 1 else 0 end) ColumnNNullCount
from MyScheme.MyTable
```